# Longest x86 Instruction

Tags: disassembly, assembly, windbg

I read the recent article "Longest x86 Instruction"

http://blog.onlinedisassembler.com/blog/?p=23

I attempted to reproduce the curious disassembly issue on a Win7x86 development platform using masm and as the article suggested, redunant prefixes.

Talk is cheap, so here's a toy program (masm32):

```
.386 .model flat, stdcall

option casemap:none

includelib \x\x\kernel32.lib
includelib \x\x\user32.lib

include \x\x\kernel32.inc
include \x\x\user32.inc
include \x\x\windows.inc

.code

start:

db 0F3h
db 0F3h
db 0F3h
db 0F3h
db 0F3h
db 0F3h
db 0F3h
;...6 more bytes later
db 089h
db 0E5h

end start

invoke ExitProcess, NULL
```

After linking and assembling, I opened the resulting executable in windbg.

To my disappointment, when I single step, unassemble the $exentry, etc. windbg simply sees the prefixes/bytes as individual instructions, says 'to hell with it' and executes only the valid instructions.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Saying 'to hell with it' seems to be the best thing a debugger can do when it sees unneccesary redundant prefixes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about processor features, not reverse engineering.

Comment: On the contrary, attempting to discern the processor's behavior is a form of reverse engineering.

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: "windbg .. executes only the valid instructions" -- it cannot *but* execute the REPEs, but it only *halts* on certain positions. Similarly, it cannot stop "in the middle of", for example, `mov al, fs:[ebx+4*edx]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing?

The disconnect is that the [ODA](http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) disassembler referenced in http://blog.onlinedisassembler.com/blog/?p=23 produces different output than WinDbg's disassembler given the same input.

Perhaps what you're "missing" is based on the assumption that all disassemblers produce the same output given the same input, which is not a correct assumption to make.

Comment: you're right, I just realized the OS's/software's disassembler isn't 1:1 with processor behavior, e.g. like Windows not implementing Ring2 although 80386+ gives you that CPL. Updated my question on another stackExhange [link] (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/275719/longest-x86-instruction/275750#275750)